# JavaScript: Writing convention and the differences

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, framerjs

I am confused with the way I write my [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)and I am wondering what are the differences between? They all generate the same result but which is the best way to write it?

I am using `Framer.js` library for prototyping. I do aware `Framer.js` uses [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript)but I am writing them in vanilla [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

**Difference 1**

```
framerOnboard.card1.states.animationOptions({
    curve: "spring(200, 20, 0)"
});

framerOnboard.card1.states.animationOptions = {
    curve: "spring(200, 20, 0)"
};
```

**Difference 2**

```
framerOnboard.card1.states["switch"]("two");

framerOnboard.card1.states.switch("two");
```

Comment: The first two are not equivalent. The last two are.

Comment: The idea of dot notation for property names is to save some typing, so if the names are suitable, use dots. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Difference 1**

**animationOptions.-** It is a function that receives as a parameter an object. This object has a key and this key has a string value.

```
framerOnboard.card1.states.animationOptions({
    curve: "spring(200, 20, 0)"
});
```

**animationOptions.-** It is an object with a key and this key has a string value.

```
framerOnboard.card1.states.animationOptions = {
    curve: "spring(200, 20, 0)"
};
```

---

**Difference 2**

There is no difference.

Check this example:

```
var framerOnboard = {};
framerOnboard.card1 = {};
framerOnboard.card1.states = {};
framerOnboard.card1.states.switch = function(arg) // It's a function.
{
    alert(arg);
};
```

You can execute this functions in two ways:

```
framerOnboard.card1.states["switch"]("two");
```

Or

```
framerOnboard.card1.states.switch("two");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/un693467/1/

Comment: If you declare a variable as {} what does this mean in Javascript sense? Making it into an object?

Comment: Yes, it's an object.
Check this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/c4qud6co/

Answer (score 1):

**Difference 1:**

The first one you are invoking the method `animationOptions` and using `{curve: "spring(200, 20, 0)"}` as the argument. The second one you are setting `framerOnboard.card1.states.animationOptions` to be an object with a key as `'curve'` and the value as `"spring(200, 20, 0)"`.

**Difference 2:**

They both do the same thing, which is to invoke the method switch with `"two"` as the argument. However. the first one is called bracket notation and the second one is called dot notation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) are some use cases for one over the other.